# Understanding Typescript code example based on uniswap code

Tags: typescript

In the uniswap website there is the following code in the Swap page (https://github.com/Uniswap/interface/blob/main/src/pages/Swap/index.tsx line 115)

```
const {
    trade: { state: tradeState, trade },
    allowedSlippage,
    currencyBalances,
    parsedAmount,
    currencies,
    inputError: swapInputError,
  } = useDerivedSwapInfo()
```

Based on my limmited understanding of typescript what is happening is: 1) The output of `useDerivedSwapInfo()` is being destructured. 2) One of the variables is `trade` which has the type `{ state: tradeState, trade }`. But based on the further usage in the code where actually `tradeState` and the 'other' `trade` are being used, this makes no sense.

Could anyone help me understand this code? What does the line `trade: { state: tradeState, trade }` actually do

Answer (score 2):

> 1. The output of `useDerivedSwapInfo()` is being destructured.

Correct!

> 2. One of the variables is trade which has the type `{ state: tradeState, trade }`.

No, I can see how you go there but that's nested destructuring along with some renaming in the destructuring. It's taking `x.trade.state` and `x.trade.trade` and putting them in `tradeState` and `trade` respectively (where `x` is the return value of `useDerivedSwapInfo()`).

Here's the non-destructuring near-equivalent of that code:

```
const x = useDerivedSwapInfo();
const tradeState = x.trade.state;
const trade = x.trade.trade;
const allowedSlippage = x.allowedSlippage;
const currencyBalance = x.currencyBalances;
const parsedAmount = x.parsedAmount;
const currencies = x.currencies;
const swapInputError = x.inputError;
```

*("near-equivalent" because `x.trade` wouldn't actually be read twice as it is above.)*